# copying a string in an array element of a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, strcpy

I have the following problem: I made this node structure

```
typedef struct NODE{
    struct NODE *sons[1024];             //this array will be used to store  children pointers
    char name[255];
    int leaf;                   

}NODE;
```

and this function to create a new node with a given name. The problem is that the first printf shows the right name, the second one doesn't. It seems like the for loop erases the name and I can't explain myself why...

```
NODE *AllocateNewNode( char *inputname) {
    NODE *newnode;
    newnode = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));



    memset(newnode->name, '\0', sizeof(newnode->name));


    strcpy(newnode->name, inputname);    

    printf("node %s created\n", newnode->name);   //right name in the output


    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1024; i++) {

        newnode->sons[i] = NULL;
    }

    newnode->leaf = 1;


    printf("node %s created\n", newnode->name);        //no name in the output

    return newnode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing past the end of your sons array;

Should be `for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {` since there are only 1024 elements in the array 0...1023.

Comment: @Speck if this is the answer you were expecting, you should accept it.